# Mysql(Mariadb) die after 5 minutes

Tags: mysql, mariadb, digital-ocean

I have a VPS server. It's running on Centos 7.
I set up one website on it with around 100 visit/per day.
This week, it suddenly die after 5 minutes. I can not access to my website.
I have to restart mysql to using it each time.
Please help me!!!!
[image: When server die]

Comment: Please check the error log (at `/var/log/mysqld.err`, `/var/log/mysql/mysql.err` or `.../*.log` or something similar). It should tell you why the process crashed. If you need help understanding the content, add the end of it (that describes the crash) to your question (although it probably fits better on dba.stackexchange.com)

Comment: Let's see `my.cnf`; perhaps you raised some setting too high.  How much RAM do you have?  High CPU or Load Average usually indicates a query with an inadequate index; let's see the query.  Do `SHOW PROCESSLIST`.